# Como acessar Action em outro Controller via Ajax?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax, razor, post

Tenho um projeto AspNet MVC estruturado da seguinte maneira:

```
Projeto
    L
      Areas
         L
           Area1
               L
                Controllers
                       L
                        MeuControllerArea1Controller.cs
                Views
           Area2
               L
                Controllers
                       L
                        MeuControllerArea2Controller.cs
                Views
                     L
                       MinhaView.cshtml
```

Em **MeuControllerArea1**, tenho um método público (**MinhaActionArea1**) que retorna um `json`, quero acessa-lo de **MinhaView** que está em **Area2**.

O código abaixo não tem funcionado, pois ao ser executado, ele busca **MinhaActionArea1** em **MeuControllerArea2**.

```
function ObterResultado() {
        $.post('@Url.Action("MinhaActionArea1", "../Area1/MeuControllerArea1")')
            .done(function (data) {
                // Código de sucesso...
            })
            .fail(function () {
                // Código de falha...
            });
    }
```

> Obs: Estou usando [AreaRegistration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.mvc.arearegistration(v=vs.118).aspx).

Comment: $.post('../Area1/MeuControllerArea1/MinhaActionArea1')

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, poste como resposta @JoaoPaulo a falha era minha aqui.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depois da dica do @JoaoPaulo nos comentários consegui perfeitamente usando:

```
$.post('../Area1/MeuControllerArea1/MinhaActionArea1')
```

Outra opção (a qual escolhi) pode ser feita com [UrlHelper.Action Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action(v=vs.118).aspx), pois como observei no final da pergunta, estou usando [AreaRegistration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.mvc.arearegistration(v=vs.118).aspx).

Pesquisei e encontrei uma [outra forma](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper.Action%28System.String,System.String,System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary%29) de usar o **@Url.Action** passando justamente a `area` a qual se encontra o `controller` e `action`:

```
@Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName", new { area = "AreaName" })
```

O código ficou assim:

```
function ObterResultado() {
        $.post('@Url.Action("MinhaActionArea1", "MeuControllerArea1", new { area = "Area1" })')
            .done(function (data) {
                // Código de sucesso...
            })
            .fail(function () {
                // Código de falha...
            });
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Basta colocar como string, não precisa usar o código C#:

```
$.post('../Area1/MeuControllerArea1/MinhaActionArea1')
```